# R: Divide all values in columns starting with "stage" by values in a column called time: rowwise

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a dataframe df containing a column of times and values in a set of columns called stage 1, stage 2,...,stage_50. I would like to divide all the values in the columns stage_1 to stage_50 by the corresponding value in the time column.

```
df<-data.frame(time=runif(10)*60,stage_1=runif(10)*10,stage_2=runif(10)*10, someOtherColumn=rep("A",10))
```

I can select the columns called stage and put them in another df.

```
df1<-df %>%
select(starts_with("stage")
```

then divide:

```
df1/df$time
```

but that doesn't seem very satisfactory. How can I use `starts_with` inside mutate?

e.g.

```
df%>%
mutate(starts_with("stage")/time)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) across** Use across:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("stage"), ~ . / time))
```

It could alternately be written like this:

```
df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("stage"), `/`, time))
```

**2) pivot** Another way to do this is to reshape into long form, perform the division and then reshape back.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("stage")) %>%
  mutate(value = value / time) %>%
  pivot_wider
```

**3) base R**  It can also be done readily in base R:

```
ok <- startsWith(names(df), "stage")
replace(df, ok, df[ok] / df$time)
```

**4) ftransformv** The collapse package has ftransformv to apply the indicated function to the selected columns.  It is written in C/C++ and  runs 13x faster than the base solution, 112x faster than the dplyr solution and 363x faster than the tidyr solution when I benchmarked it.

```
library(collapse)
ftransformv(df, startsWith(names(df), "stage"), `/`, time)
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Favourite new command: across!